# Get next pPrimary key id with lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 5 and I need to get next id in table like

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want to get next id, when my id is 1 want to get next id 2

```
public class Level
{
    [Key]
    public int LevelID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public int Statue { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int? SessionCount { get; set; }
    public int? SessionAttend { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }
    public Guid UserAddID { get; set; }
    public Guid userEditID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool DelFlag { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DelDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserDelID { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need the next primary key? It should be assigned by your database.

Comment: in my application wanna move group to the next level

Comment: What exactly do you need to know - the highest id in the table, the next highest id from current, or something else? What have you tried?

Comment: just i wanna get next id !

Comment: Just let the **database** handle this - use an `INT IDENTITY` in SQL Server and be done with it. Don't try to determine this yourself in code - you can only fail at this and get duplicates - which is **NOT** a good idea for a primary key!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int getNextId(int id)
{
  var nextEntities = repository.Query<Levels>().OrderBy(d=>d.LevelId)
  .Where(l=>l.LevelId>id)
  .Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
  return  nextEntities != null ? nextEntities.LevelId : ++id; //or return 0 on your choice
}
```

Comment: Again: word of warning: this is **HIGHLY suspectible** to producing duplicate values, which is an absolute NO-NO for a primary key! This just cannot be properly handled in code - this needs to be done on the database level!

Comment: is not known exactly how the author is going to use this code. Perhaps it is to find a new record id, or locate an existing entity, following the current

Answer (score 0):

To get the next LevelId that would be assigned for a new row you could probably use this:

```
var nextId = db.Levels.OrderBy(x => x.LevelId).Last().LevelId + 1;
```

I probably wouldn't recommend this though. The whole idea wreaks of bad code smell to me.

Comment: Just be aware: this approach is **HIGHLY** vulnerable to producing duplicate values, which is not a good idea for a primary key!